# Save data offline from a selected book by user in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that gives to the user all chapters of a book. I want to make each chapter downloadable if the user wants to download it, with a button. I would like to know how to do this. I'm using Firebase Realtime to get these chapters from an online DB. Should I save the downloaded chapters in a local database on phone or have another way? I'm already using `dbref.keepSynced(true)` and `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)`. But I want to save in cache just the chapters name, not the text of the chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make each chapter downloadable if the user wants to download it, with a button.

You can indeed create a local database like [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), but I don't think that's really necessary since the Realtime Database already provides an [offline persistence mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

> Should I save the downloaded chapters in a local database on phone or have another way?

This is what the Firebase Android SDK already does.

Comment: But I don't want to save all books the user open, just those He choose

Comment: Yes, it will save only the books that the user opens. It won't save all books unless the user explicitly opens all of them.

Comment: So, can I help you with other information regarding this question?